# external usb keyboard not fully working on android tablet

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, usb, keyboard, external-keyboard

I have two Android tablets. I connected an external keyboard via USB and the only key that is working is <kbd>backspace</kbd>, other keys don't work.

What can I do to  solve this problem?

Comment: First, the details you provided are far from being sufficient for giving good answers here (which most likely is why you didn't receive any yet). If the issue still exists, please [edit] your post and add at least: 1) brand and name of the tablets 2) brand and name of the keyboards. Without that, the only possible advice is: a) try different keyboards b) try different tablets.